# Intel Wifi is not working and is unclaimed on hp au114tx

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I have recently installed ubuntu. And I am facing an issue of Wifi that is not working since installation. On running:

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

I get the following message on wireless network:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b4000000-b4001fff
```

and on running

```
iwconfig
```

I get:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u2  no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

and `lspci -nnk | grep A2 Network` gives:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 
Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

I am new to Ubuntu please help me.

Comment: Sir `lspci =nnk | grep -A2 Network` command has been edited BUT `sudo dmesg |grep iwlwifi` yeilds nothing

Comment: That's fine and still tells us something. What's the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`? Is the `linux-firmware` package installed?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627114) that is supposedly fixed with the kernel in Zesty but a work-around is available at least for Ubuntu Xenial, possibly earlier releases too.

Comment: Thank you sir, I upgraded my kernel to 4.8 and now everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you David sir.. It would be my pleasure by having an upvote from  you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving time to me...

My Wireless started working on UPGRADING the kernel to 4.8
and running the command:

`sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: This command could not upgrade to 4.8. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Yes ofcourse this command cannot upgrade the kernel, you have to look up online for the package. I meant that by upgrading the kernel to 4.8 and running this command could solve the problem. Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: P.S.: You need to mention my user name if you want to notify me through a comment like so: @VishalMaurya